# How to let emacs use 256 colors in console

Tags: emacs

I have set `TERM=xterm-256color` in env, and `tput colors` shows 256, but emacs still only shows 16 colors.

How can I enable emacs to use 256 colors?

Comment: is `M-x list-colors-display` showing 256 colors?

Comment: no `M-x list-colors-display` shows only 16 colors.

Comment: Suppose you run `export TERM=rxvt`, then run emacs and run `M-x list-colors-display` ?